# Overflowing and oversized text in mobile Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, mozilla

I have tried to find more about this but I have so far been unlucky.  My website loads and looks how I want across IE11, FF, and Chrome.  However, when I go to test it on my phone, it looks incorrect in both FF and Chrome.  I am using a Samsung S4.  I tried to access my site using an iPhone 5s and the problem is still there.  I am unsure how to make my site cooperate with these apps because I am very new to web design.  I have looked up ways to make my website more mobile friendly but I want to know if its possible to simply make it look the same across each platform.  Here is a JSFiddle of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/willwsharp/da775/

However, the problem only exists if I view the JSFiddle on my phone.  To be more specific, the menu buttons overflow the website menu by a little, the footer text at the bottom spills outside the div and the actual information on the different pages seems to ignore the borders that of their divs.  I know my code doesn't look good either, I am in the process of going back and fleshing it out.

I am using a reset css files to standardize all the little nuances between the browsers; here is that code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle link is broken: it's probably not a public fiddle.

Comment: @SamHuckaby I will fix that, that is odd.
EDIT: I believe it should be fixed.

Comment: While your exact issue could be a number of things (can't yet see the Fiddle) try out the Emulation tools in the "Drawer" part of the Chrome developer tools. They can sometimes apply the effect of small screens that you can't get just by resizing the browser.

Comment: @Katana314 I will be sure to do that.  I have been using the Netbeans IDE for web development, and it allows me to resize the screen to view it from different devices, but that shows no problem on the cell-phone view.

EDIT:  I just tried doing the Emulation tools through Chrome, and it shows no problem either.

Comment: nothing wrong with style reset... remember style reset doesn't 100% compatibility across all browsers. You must be using some UN-compatible properties for mobile browsers. I recommend try mobile debugging.

Comment: @AamirShahzad Do you mean with a specific kind of mobile debugging or how do you propose I do that?

Comment: @Willwsharp i use Weinre for remote debuging.. it actually allows you to inspect like firebug remotely on mobile... there are plenty of other tools available. Choose one which suits you...